# Cannot boot my computer. Hard Drive is not recognized by BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I have an ASUS Laptop running Windows 8.1 (K55A-DH51 Intel Core i5-3210M 2.50GHz - 750GB)

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu. I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 from an USB drive (I modified my BIOS so that it would boot from my USB and start the installer).

Everything was going great until the installer did not recognize Windows 8, so I clicked the "Something else" option in the installer and was presented with a list of partitions (I believe that's what they were) and that is when I decided to quit the installation as I did not know what to do.

I then tried to boot to Windows, but my computer kept going to my BIOS. I checked my Boot menu and tried to change my Boot priority to my Hard Drive but I did not see that option. I am not sure what to do as I can't tell my BIOS to boot from my hard drive, even when I reset it to it's defaults settings.

I have tried multiple things (including Boot-repair, which gave me this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7094345/ ) but I don't understand most of the terms and procedures. I am currently running Ubuntu from my USB drive but I want to go back to Windows. I don't want to lose my files.

I think I just need to to find a way for my BIOS to recognize my hard drive and tell it to boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CD/DVD of your Windows (The clean solution) :

1. Boot from Windows CD/DVD and choose “Repair” when it shows up.
2. Choose Command Prompt on the resulting screen and run the following
   two commands:

   `bootrec /fixmbr`

   `bootrec /fixboot`
3. Remove the CD/DVD and you should boot straight into Windows

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you have done while installing, but it looks like you have accidentally overwritten your windows partition with a blank ext2 partition. The boot-repair paste shows that you don't have any operating system currently installed. So it would appear that windows has somehow been deleted. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the files are probably already gone... I hope you kept backups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: burn super GRUB2 DISK http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ this will tell you if you have your windows yet or lost it !!